# SQL Server Exists predicate

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

I understand that this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL) PRINT 'TRUE';
```

would always print `TRUE` because after all `NULL` is a value in SQL Server but why would this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL) PRINT 'TRUE'
```

print `TRUE` as the sub query would cause an error and `EXISTS` always checks for existence so how come this is possible.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but both those lines look the same to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing because there is a copy/paste error in your question

EXISTS doesn't check for values. It checks for rows.

So these are valid because the SELECT gives one row

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1/0) PRINT 'TRUE' 
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL) PRINT 'TRUE';
IF EXISTS(SELECT CAST('fish' AS int)) PRINT 'TRUE';
```

To explain, we'll look at [ANSI-92 SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), search for "`Query expressions   191`".

This is case 3a (my bold):

> If the `<select list> "*"` is simply contained in a `<subquery>`
>                 that is immediately contained in an `<exists predicate>`, then
>                 the `<select list>` is equivalent to a `<value expression>` that
>                 is an **arbitrary** `<literal>`.

So, this says you can have any old rubbish in the EXISTS bit: it should be ignored